# My jest test is failing for my controller with a json method missing error

Tags: node.js, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a controller that registers a user, however, testing it does not work. I am using Jest in Node version 16.  Here is the controller: I get the following error
TypeError: response.status(...).json is not a function

I did implement the json method of the object so I don't know why I'm getting this error

```js
        class AuthenticationController {

        registerNewUser = async(request:Request, response:Response, next:NextFunction) =>{
            const username = request.body.username
            const password = request.body.password
            if(!username || !password){
                
                response.status(400).json({success:false, 'no username or password'}) 
            }
            const query = {username: username}
            const user = await User.findOne(query)
            if(user){
               response.status(400).json({message: 'User exists'})
            } 
            const hashUtility = new HashUtil()
            const {hash}  = hashUtility.createHash(password)
            const createQuery = (username: username,hash:hash)
            await User.create( createQuery)
            // TypeError: response.status(...).json is not a function
            // is now thrown here
            response.status(200).json(createQuery)   
        }
    
    
    }

    export {AuthenticationController}
```

Here is my test class

```js
    describe('UserAuthController test suite', ()=>{
            let authController:AuthenticationController 
           
            beforeEach(()=>{
               authController  = new AuthenticationController()
            })
           it('should successfully register a new user ', async ()=>{
             let user  = new User({
                username: 'user@gmail.com',
                hash: 'ddh44500000',
              })
           
            let mockRequest = {
                body: {
                username: 'user@gmail.com',
                password: 'mypassword'
               }
             }
            let responseObject = {};
            let mockResponse: Partial<Response> = {
              statusCode: 200,
              status: jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=>200),
              json: jest.fn().mockImplementation((result) =>{
                responseObject = result
              })
          }
             UserConfig.findOne = 
                 jest.fn().mockImplementation((query)=>{
                   return null
             })
             let next = jest.fn()
             let hashUtility = new HashUtil()
             jest.spyOn(hashUtility, 'createHash').mockImplementationOnce((password) =>{
               return {hash: 'ddh44500000'}
              })
            await authController.registerNewUser(mockRequest as Request, mockResponse as 
            Response, next)
            console.log(`ResponseObjeect ${responseObject}`)
       })
     })
```

I don't know what I'm missing in my test code. Please help

Comment: Your middleware code is calling `response.status(400).json({/* ... */})`; is the **status** method supposed to return the response object so that other method call can be chained? I think In your `mockResponse` object (in the test code), `status: jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=>200)` should be `status: jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=> mockResponse)`.

Comment: I copied the wrong request for another mockRequest. I fixed that.Even when I pass the password, I still get the missing json method.

Comment: Did you actually read my comment? I just posted an answer with the same fix that I've described in my previous comment and it worked. And for God's sake, please don't add code snippets with multiple syntax error .

Comment: Please don't edit my answer to reply or ask for clarifications rather write a comment below my answer. Also, I highly suggest reading the [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started), it contains everything you need to know to solve your jest related problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not creating your `mockResponse` object properly.

You're response object's methods should support method chaining as described in your code:

```js
 response.status(200).json({ message: "msg" });
```

In order to be able to call `.json({ message: "msg" })` the previous `status` method must return `this` (the `response` object).

But in you're test code you've the following:

```
let mockResponse: Partial<Response> = {
  statusCode: 200,
  status: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 200),
  json: jest.fn().mockImplementation((result) => {
    responseObject = result;
  }),
};
```

So, when you pass this mock response object to the middle-ware and it calls `response.status(400)` it returns `200` (according to your `jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 200)`).

Then it chains the `.json({})` call but as the returned value from previous call was `200`, so `(200).json({...})` throws an error:

> TypeError: response.status(...).json is not a function

This is an easy fix, you just need to return the `mockResponse` object from each mock methods, like the following snippet:

```js
let responseObject = {};
let mockResponse = {
  statusCode: 200,
  status: jest.fn().mockImplementation((status) => mockResponse),
  json: jest.fn().mockImplementation((result) => {
    responseObject = result;
    return mockResponse
  }),
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I solved it using chaining as you advised. Thank you very much!